# Multiple Js files not working in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a weird problem here, i have a page called index.php where in the head section i am including 5 Javascript files, but all of them are not working except the first js file. When i move my entire code to one file they start working but the moment i switch them back to from where they belong they stopped working and i have tried including the files before the body they don't work.

Any help

Thanks

Comment: Any errors in your JavaScript console? Is this *only* with Chrome?

Comment: nope no errors in firebug on any javascript debugger i am using

Comment: The most likely explanation is that file 2 is calling a function defined in file 5. Perhaps when they were combined, you put the contents of file 5 before the contents of file 2, fixing the problem?

Comment: that is not the exact problem let say i have 5 files "custom.js","jquery.js","validate.js" and any other two . If i will move custom.js to first place when including it in my index.php it will start working , but if will include jquery.js first that will start working . SO PROBLEM IS WHICHEVER FILE IS CALLED FIRST IS WORKING NOT THE REST OF THE FILES

Comment: And yeah everything is working fine in firefox and even IE

Comment: You want to show the HTML, or do you want us to just guess a bunch of different things?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="name">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Admin Template</title>
<!-- tdeme Start -->
<link href="css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- tdeme End -->
<!-- calendar source files --> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/validate-edit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/validate-asset.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

Comment: Okay, so only the first JS file works, whichever one that happens to be. If you put some javascript in the body, does it work?

Comment: What causes you to say they don't work? Are you getting an error, or is there some other way you are determining this? Also, when you look at the HTML in the developer tools, do all the script elements appear as children of the head?

Comment: yes if i write my code in the html file it do work but once moving them back they stopped working and there is not any errors i have some slide down functions and they are not working at all without any console error

Comment: Can you post a link to either a page that demonstrates your problem so others can try to duplicate it and fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short:  Save all of your files in UTF-8 format and try your page again.  :)

I had the same exact problem.  It was driving me mad, because I know this works!  Many sites on the Internet include several JS files, and they were all working.

I finally figured out that my code editor (Notepad++) was set to save files in ANSI format.  I changed the editor's setting to save files as UTF-8 and everything is working again.

I found this by opening the Chrome developer console on the broken page (Ctrl+Shift+I).  I expanded the "<head>" section, and saw three "<script>" entries.  I double-clicked on the link in the "src" attribute of the second "<script>" tag to see if I could at least view the broken JavaScript file from within the developer console.  When the new page opened, it gave me a syntax error and showed me a bunch of Chinese characters.  This was my clue that the file over on my web server had been saved in some format that my browser was not interpreting correctly.